# Dynamically updated data with highstock

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

I have a MySQL database that gets updated every 5 seconds with a time-stamp and temperature.

I'm trying to represents the live data using high stock.

Here's my code so far:

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*******";
$database = "MicroCSP";
$port = 3306;

header("Content-type: text/html");

$con = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$database,$port);

if ($con->connect_error)
{
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql="select TimeStamp as time,Pdc2 as temperature from SpotData";

if ($result = $con->query($sql)) {

// $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
$rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row){

$datetime = ($row['time'])*1000;
$temp = $row['temperature'];

$data[] = "[$datetime, $temp]";
}
//$data[] = "[$datetime, $out]";
//echo(json_encode($data));

$result->close();
} 
else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$con->close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
   Temps Reel
 </title>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <script>

  $(function () {

      Highcharts.setOptions({
          global : {
              useUTC : false
          }
      });

      // Create the chart
      $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
          chart : {
              events : {
                  load : function () {

                      // set up the updating of the chart each 5 seconds
                      var series = this.series[0];
                      setInterval(function () {
                          var x = <?php echo $datetime; ?>, //<?php echo $datetime; ?>  // current time 
                               y = <?php echo $temp; ?>//Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                          series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                      }, 5000);
                  }
              }
          },
          
          rangeSelector: {
              buttons: [{
                  count: 1,
                  type: 'minute',
                  text: '1M'
              }, {
                  count: 5,
                  type: 'minute',
                  text: '5M'
              }, {
                  type: 'all',
                  text: 'All'
              }],
              inputEnabled: false,
              selected: 0
          },

          title : {
              text : 'Live random data'
          },

          exporting: {
              enabled: false
          },

          series : [{
              name : 'Data',
              data : [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>],
          }]
      });

  });

 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I use the built-in date function and random values it works just fine but when I try to echo out data from my database it doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Have you seen Highcharts docs about live data? I think that may help you with your issue: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

Comment: i did but it didn't help